# Did Prophet Solomon posses horses that were able to fly?

Tags: hadith, prophets

In a hadith, Prophet Muhammed found Aisha's dolls had horses with wings on it. On the Prophet's enquiry, she replied suleiman's horses had wings. The reason I'm asking this is many critics/ islamophobes speak about flying horses.

I believe they connect flying horse event to meraj event.

> Prophet said, “What is this I see?” Aisha said, “A horse,” The Prophet said, “What is this on it?” Aisha said, “Two wings.” The Prophet said, “A horse with two wings?” Aisha said, “Have you not heard that Solomon had horses with two wings?” The Prophet laughed so deeply that his molar teeth could be seen.
>
> Source: [Sunan Abī Dāwūd 4932](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/160)

my question is did suleiman's horses flew or they had wings like ostrich and emu?

Comment: First of all the hadith is about having fun and laughing with children as 'Aishah was just a child girl who played with her friends. And the statement you are asking about are the words of this 7 years old girl. Secondly you may also read in the qur'an (38:31) which is relevant.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Perhaps you meant 38:31 which is where horses are mentioned.

Comment: Please note that the Buraq isn't exactly a horse. It is celestial creature that 'looked like a horse with wings'.

Comment: @Ahmed, buraq was a creature smaller than horse larger than donkey, which travelled on earth and didnt have wings see bukhari hadith

Comment: @Preordainment Can you share the link to the hadith or it's number in Bukhari. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This hadith does not specifically show that Sulaiman (AS) had flying horses since the Prophet (SAW) didn't say anything to confirm it.

However, Sulaiman (AS) was given much more amazing powers than just flying horses. Allah says in the Quran:

> And to Solomon [We subjected] the wind - its morning [journey was that of] a month - and its afternoon [journey was that of] a month, and We made flow for him a spring of [liquid] copper. And among the jinn were those who worked for him by the permission of his Lord. And whoever deviated among them from Our command - We will make him taste of the punishment of the Blaze. (34:12)

He had control of the wind and control of the Jinn!

Furthermore, under his command were beings who could carry a throne thousands of kilometers in the blink of an eye:

> Said one who had knowledge from the Scripture, "I will bring it [the throne] to you before your glance returns to you." And when [Solomon] saw it placed before him, he said, "This is from the favor of my Lord to test me whether I will be grateful or ungrateful. And whoever is grateful - his gratitude is only for [the benefit of] himself. And whoever is ungrateful - then indeed, my Lord is Free of need and Generous." (27:40)

I would not be surprised at all even if Sulaiman (AS) was given horses that could fly because he was given things much more amazing than that. It is an extremely weak argument critics of Islam use if they use this. Allah is all-Powerful and He certainly does not lack the ability to create flying horses and much more than that.

Comment: How are ifreet considered as people? Tacit approval, smile is considered as affirmation in hadith science

Comment: @Preordainment Firstly, that is not an Ifreet. The Ifreet was the one who offered to bring the throne before he could get up from his sitting place. Secondly, people is probably a poor choice of words on my part. I meant "beings."

As for affirmation in hadith, that is usually true, but in this case it isn't clear-cut because it is a playful conversation with Aisha (RA).

Comment: The person that essentially bought the throne wasn't he a human with the name Asif Barkhia?

Comment: Read Quran 27:42, a human bought the throne that had the knowledge of the scriptures and was close to Allah.